# Large batch Inserts Using Snowflake & Go

Tags: go, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am retrieving payloads from a REST API with which I then want to insert into a Snowflake table.

My current process is to use the Snowflake DB connection and iterate over a slice of structs (which contain my data from the API). However, this doesn't seem to be efficient or optimal. Everything is successfully loading, but I am trying to figure out how to optimize a large amount of inserts for potentially thousands of records. Perhaps there needs to be a separate channel for insertions instead of synchronously inserting?

General code flow:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake"
)


func ETL() {
     var wg sync.WaitGroup
     ch := make(chan []*Response)
     defer close(ch)
     
     // Create requests to API
     for _, req := range requests {
          // All of this flows fine without issue
          wg.Add(1)
          go func(request Request) {
               defer wg.Done()
               resp, _ := request.Get() 
               ch <- resp
          }(request)
     }

     // Connect to snowflake
     // This is not a problem
     connString := fmt.Sprintf(config...)
     db, _ := sql.Open("snowflake", connString)
     defer db.Close()

     // Collect responses from our channel
     results := make([][]*Response, len(requests))
     for i, _ := range results {
         results[i] <-ch
         for _, res :=  range results[i] {
             // transform is just a function to flatten my structs into entries that I would like to insert into Snowflake. This is not a bottleneck.
             entries := transform(res)

             // Load the data into snowflake, passing the entries that have been
             // Flattened as well as the db connection
             err := load(entries, db)
         }
     }
}

type Entry struct {
    field1 string
    field2 string
    statusCode int
}

func load(entries []*Entry, db *sql.DB) error {
    start := time.Now()
    for i, entry := range entries {
        fmt.Printf("Loading entry %d\n", i)

        stmt := `INSERT INTO tbl (field1, field2, updated_date, status_code)
             VALUES (?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), ?)`

        _, err := db.Exec(stmt, entry.field1, entry.field2, entry.statusCode)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return err
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Load time: ", time.Since(start))
    return nil
}
```

Comment: You definitely want to avoid using INSERT statements.  I would consider dropping your payload directly to blob storage and then calling the snowpipe API to ingest the entire payload in micro-batches.  That should be far more efficient.  I would also suggest loading the data as-is into Snowflake, rather than flattening it out in Go.  You can throw a view over it to flatten it or query it directly as a variant data type instead.

Comment: @MikeWalton Great advice. Thanks. I was debating on whether its a better idea to load it as json variants, but I'd like the data to be available near real-time. Would the flattening process come thru the snowpipe? I haven't used SnowPipe yet but am vaguely familiar with its usage.

Comment: Snowpipe can sometimes be used to flatten depending on how much transformation is needed, but if you ingest directly as variant json, then it can be queried in near real-time using a view or materialized view or directly in sql using the Snowflake json syntax.

Comment: The other benefit of this method is you will never have a field change from the source create an error in your process.  New attributes just get stored in JSON until you update the view.  Updating the view in that case doesn't require reloading the data or altering a table with a bunch of data in it.  So, maintenance is as easy as just updating the view.

Comment: @MikeWalton Thanks Mike! Really helpful. I think Snowpipe requires a Java or Python API instead of Go?

Comment: You can setup Snowpipe to auto-ingest, as well, so no need to do anything in Go other than create the file on blob.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `INSERT`ing individual rows, collect rows in files and each time you push one of these to S3/GCS/Azure it will be loaded immediately.

I wrote a post detailing these steps:

- https://medium.com/snowflake/lightweight-batch-streaming-to-snowflake-with-gcp-pub-sub-1790ab76da31

With the appropriate storage integration, this would auto-ingest the files:

```sql
create pipe temp.public.meetup202011_pipe
auto_ingest = true
integration = temp_meetup202011_pubsub_int
as
copy into temp.public.meetup202011_rsvps
from @temp_fhoffa_gcs_meetup;
```

Also check these considerations:

- https://www.snowflake.com/blog/best-practices-for-data-ingestion/

Soon: If you want to send individual rows and ingest them in real time into Snowflake - that's in development (https://www.snowflake.com/blog/snowflake-streaming-now-hiring-help-design-and-build-the-future-of-big-data-and-stream-processing/).